# The mysql_num_rows function returns 0 on an older version of phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginning php-programmer and have tried to create a registration/login system with a database. The system works at home on the latest version of phpmyadmin but my school hasn't updated it to the latest version yet (don't worry, this isn't homework). The problem I have is that at school `mysql_num_rows` returns 0 when I try to login but returns 1 when I try to login at home. My teacher said the version of phpmyadmin might be causing this problem. Version at school is: 4.5.2.

Here's my login.php file:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

session_start();
$error = "";
$emailaddress = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if(empty($emailaddress) || empty($password)){
    $error = "Email or password is invalid!";
    echo $error;
}
else{
    $queryforlogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailaddress='$emailaddress' AND password='$password'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($queryforlogin);

    if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['login_user'] = mysql_query("SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE emailaddress='$emailaddress'");
        $username = mysql_fetch_array($_SESSION['login_user']);
        echo "Welcome, " . $username['firstname'] . "!";
    }
    else{
        $error = "Email or password not found!";
        echo $error;
    }
    mysql_close($connect);
}

?>
```

If I click the login button on the webpage, it gives me the error: Email or password not found! (the last else-statement). It executes the code in the file but does not execute the code under if($rows==1).
Is there anything I can do to still get this code to work?
Again, this code does work at home but not at school on an older version. I asked my teacher if he could update phpmyadmin but other classes are working with phpmyadmin right now so that cannot be done.
I hope you understand my question.
Sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

Comment: @JohnAnkanna What did you change in the query? Isn't it exactly the same?

Comment: check how many users you have into database with tested mail and password, i.e. is there possibility $rows to be more than 1? and something else - in first result set you already have user details (firstname) so is not necessary to make another call to db.

Comment: @mitkosoft That might be the problem. I noticed that at the older version at school, the Auto Increment of the id doesn't reset to 1 when I delete all the users in the table. Maybe the users are "still there" but just invisible. Could that be it?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is just web interface for MySql database. PHP code has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin. Also DON'T USE `mysql` use `PDO` ir `mysqli`

Comment: phpmyadmin is not connected at all. if you want to reset auto increment, just truncate table, not delete data. so as first step add echo $rows before your IF statement in order to check that

Comment: Did you check what mysql_num_rows() returns ?

Comment: @Justinas i will try to use mysqli.

Comment: @mitkosoft Didn't think of checking $rows before the IF statement. Will do

Comment: @Vincent Didn't think of that. Will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You just try once like this by passing `mysql_connect` connection variable in `mysql_query` so you can get the rows

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets get something right of the bat, PHPmyadmin has nothing to do with mysql_num_rows returning whatever it returns, PHPmyadmin is merely a tool to manage the database to which the server is linked to, everything happens on your server side.

I think you don't have the same username and password in your table at your school's database and hence the mysql_num_rows() returns 0, which is what it is supposed to do when the query does not yield any results, 
OR it could be that your query returns more than 1 result, in that case the condition would fail again($rows==1).

Comment: The login system uses $_POST[""] with variables. I use a different database at home which means I use different login credentials at home. Because I have a database at home and a database at school, I made an extern connect file so I can manage the different databases. Simply said,  the connection file at school is different from at home.